# How to balance data while using data generators with keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, generator

I am trying to use keras to fit a CNN model to classify 2 classes of data . I have imbalanced dataset I want to balance the data. How I can do that ??

```
def generate_arrays_for_training(indexPat, paths, start=0, end=100):
while True:
from_=int(len(paths)/100*start)
to_=int(len(paths)/100*end)
for i in range(from_, int(to_)):
f=paths[i]
x = np.load(PathSpectogramFolder+f)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)

if('P' in f):
y = np.repeat([[0,1]],x.shape[0], axis=0)
else:
y =np.repeat([[1,0]],x.shape[0], axis=0)
yield(x,y)
history=model.fit_generator(generate_arrays_for_training(indexPat, filesPath, end=75),
validation_data=generate_arrays_for_training(indexPat, filesPath, start=75),
steps_per_epoch=int((len(filesPath)-int(len(filesPath)/100*25))),
validation_steps=int((len(filesPath)-int(len(filesPath)/100*75))),
verbose=2,
epochs=15, max_queue_size=2, shuffle=True, callbacks=[callback])
```

Comment: Instead of trying to balance why not use `class_weights` when doing [`model.fit()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit)

Comment: @thushv89 I don't use `model.fit()` I use `model.fit_generator()` I don't know if I can use `class_weights="balanced"` when doing 'model.fit_generator()'